# How to express "consistently beat one's own record" concisely

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is for a write-up in an academic document stating accomplishments.

I am looking for a term that is a near-equivalent of *beat one's own record, exceed expectations* and *set new records*.

Comment: [**improve**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/improve) *To raise to a more desirable or more excellent quality or condition; make better.*

Comment: To 'best your record' but it does not include further exceed and and set new goals

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *surpass oneself* and *overachieve*.

> [**surpass**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surpass): go beyond in excellence or achievement; be superior to.
>
> [**overachieve**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Overachieve?s=t): to perform better or achieve more than expected, especially by others.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- *Outstrips [one's] previous performance*
- *Outperforms [one's] previous achievements*

Answer (score 1):

There is [*raise the bar*](http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/raise-the-bar/):

> to set a higher standard for other people to follow

Examples:

The Olympic athlete plans to *raise the bar* by setting a new World Record for her sport.

When the new professor entered the university, he *raised the bar* for the other professors because of his superior teaching skills.

Answer (score 0):

In one word, I suggest **to excel** meaning:

To show superiority; surpass oneself or others.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using "personal best" or "personal record". Runners are always striving for their PR.

Comment: I believe that the question is referring to a noun for the person who breaks their own records consistently, not the noun for the records.